# Scoping Considerations Inside Anonymous Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've misplaced my basics and have a simple scoping question: I'm running a bunch of function calls to different analytics libraries through a JQuery event listener:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
  return this.href.match(/twitter\.|facebook\.|instagram\./)
})
.on('click', function() {
  // What's faster? Caching the property of `this`:
  var t = this.title;
  fbq('track', 'Lead', { content_name: t, content_category: 'Social Link' });
  ga('send', 'event', 'Social Link', 'click', t);


  // Or just call `this.title` directly?
  fbq('track', 'Lead', { content_name: this.title, content_category: 'Social Link' });
  ga('send', 'event', 'Social Link', 'click', this.title);
});
```

Part of me is worrying that references to `this` are climbing up scope and slowing down as a result. Anyone care to explain where I went wrong?

Comment: I'm interested in what others think on this. I tend to prioritize readability of the code over these small performance improvements. Unless you are doing thousands of these calls, I wouldn't expect any noticeable difference.

Comment: I am not sure, but I would guess that a var is the fastest, because otherwise the code will have to find out what this references to